# select a date above 18:00 in a datetime SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called complaints
In complaints there is a datetime column called date.

now i need to receive back in a SQL query every inserted comlaints which came in later than 18:00 of each day.

Anyone got an idea what to do or a solution with a query?
someone said to me i could use a DATE_FORMAT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your database set up for 24-hour times, you can do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable 
WHERE HOUR(TIME(yourTable.yourDateTime)) >= 18;
```

Comment: @Flowwdelapro If your problem was solved, then you should accept an answer, so that others can see that the question is not still waiting to be answered. That is how SO works.

Answer (score 3):

In your SQL query use this where condition.

```
where time(datetimefield) > '18:00:00'
```

Try this it might help you.